# Can I get a reference to the current `ICakeContext` in my Cake build script?

Tags: cakebuild

I'm refactoring a Cake build script, and decided to introduce a class to hold some build settings that get passed around a lot and/or that exist in the global scope.

Some of the settings come from arguments, and are set using the `Argument<T>(string name, string defaultValue)` syntax.

I'd like to create something like this:

```
var context = BuildContext.FromArguments();
```

For that I need acquire an instance of the current ICakeContext. The reason for that I believe is that all methods defined in cake scripts become methods of a custom-built `ICakeContext` that probably inherits from `CakeContext` and thus can call all of its (extension) methods, but once you define a class, it becomes a nested class that no longer has access to nice helpers like `Argument<T>(name, defaultValue)`.

I was hoping I could either do `ICakeContext.Current` or simply pass `this` as in `BuildContext.FromArguments(this)` or something similar.

But the keyword `this` is not allowed at that level of a Cake script (not sure why, is the top level a static method?

So, the question is: how do I get a reference to the current `ICakeContext`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason that `this` does not work, is because of the way Roslyn implements scripting, and there is no concept of `this` in the script's outer scope.

You can access the context in a couple of different ways.

**From a `Task`:**

```
Task("MyTask")
  .Does(ctx =>
{
    BuildContext.FromArguments(ctx);
});
```

**From `Setup`/`Teardown`:**

```
Setup(ctx =>
{
    BuildContext.FromArguments(ctx);
});

Teardown(ctx =>
{
    BuildContext.FromArguments(ctx);
});
```

**From `TaskSetup`/`TaskTeardown`:**

```
TaskSetup(ctx =>
{
    BuildContext.FromArguments(ctx);
});

TaskTeardown(ctx =>
{
    BuildContext.FromArguments(ctx);
});
```

**From the outer script scope:**

```
#load "somefile.csx"

BuildContext.FromArguments(Context);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Since I wrote the code in Cake I'm PREEEEETTY sure it's correct...